# How to SSH into Pod from outside a cluster without Internet access ? (K8S)

Tags: ssh, openssh, kubernetes

I created a K8S cluster (2 nodes and 1 master), that has no access to Internet, only the piloting machine has.

I wanted to SSH into a Ubuntu-OpenSSH Pod, from outside the cluster and did a port-forwarding :

```
kubectl port-forward pod/ubuntu-ssh 30180:22
```

*Where `30180` is the container `22` the port the openssh-server is listening to inside the pod.*

**Except I get an error when I try to connect with the cluster IP :**

```
$  ssh root@192.X.X.X -p 30180
ssh: connect to host 192.X.X.X port 30180: Connection refused
```

**But it works just fine if I do it using localhost :**

```
$ ssh root@localhost -p 30180
root@localhost's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-25-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

This system has been minimized by removing packages and content that are
not required on a system that users do not log into.

To restore this content, you can run the 'unminimize' command.
Last login: Fri Jul  1 12:39:19 2022 from 127.0.0.1
root@ubuntu-ssh:~#
```

Can someone help me connect to the pod with the ip address and not localhost ?
Thanks, in advance !

For more context, I have followed this tutorial :  https://sanda-dev.medium.com/ssh-into-kubernetes-pod-without-public-ip-access-fbb9da7f7b26

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the output of `kubectl port-forward --help`, and you'll see:

```
Options:
      --address=[localhost]: Addresses to listen on (comma separated). Only accepts IP addresses or
localhost as a value. When localhost is supplied, kubectl will try to bind on both 127.0.0.1 and ::1
and will fail if neither of these addresses are available to bind.
```

By default, the port opened by `kubectl port-forward` only binds to `localhost`, so it's only available for connections that originate on the local machine. If you want to expose it outside of the machine running the `port-forward` command, add:

```
kubectl port-forward --address=0.0.0.0 ...
```

The `0.0.0.0` means "all addresses", so it will be available to connections coming in any available interfaces.

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution but I have this error instead :  

`E0706 12:37:28.964127   13042 portforward.go:406] an error occurred forwarding 30180 -> 22: error forwarding port 22 to pod 529eec269d10a6a3d7783cc77da9f3883ed1116541f2409f28f609df86018e7e, uid : exit status 1: 2022/07/06 12:37:28 socat[13290] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:22, 16): Connection refused 

E0706 12:37:28.964372   13042 portforward.go:234] lost connection to pod `

Comment: Is the pod up and running? If you repeat your original command do you see different behavior? What was the exact command line you used?

Comment: The pod is indeed up and running, but you're right I have the same error with the old behavior now. the command : `kubectl port-forward  pod/ubuntu-ssh 30180:22`

Comment: If you `kubectl exec` into the pod, is your ssh service actually running? Maybe restart the pod and try again.

Comment: I can kubectl exec into the pod, I restarted it with Docker and it's still not working, except I noticed the pod ID changed, do you think it might be the reason why it doesn't work ?

Comment: If you can get port-forward working against *at all*, then this is the solution to your original question. If you're having new issues, that's probably worth a new question. The comments aren't a great place for problem diagnosis and resolution.

Comment: Okay ! Thank you very much for your answers!